# JavaScript code broke after host site upgraded servers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Recently the host company myfantasyleague.com moved to new servers, after the move I noticed that my sites where hanging on loading, and I have narrowed it down to the "mini scoreboard ticker code" that is causing this. I don't know any JS as this code is third party and was hoping someone can look at it and see if it can be fixed. If you let the site continue to load, (it takes 2-5 min) then you will see it will load eventually and the mini scoreboard displays, but this is not normal as before the site loaded in seconds completely.

Here is this the site URL
http://www60.myfantasyleague.com/2018/home/21735#0

Here is the code that is affected, it is one or both scripts

```
<div id="scoreboard">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

//FYI: Script update as of August 28, 2008

//Start ticker manually
   var tickerClickToStart = false;

//If you wish to use icons from previous iframe ticker
   var useOldIconMethod = false;

//Icon URL including base name and extension
   var tickerIconURL = '';
   var tickerIconExt = 'gif';

//Use current league icons  
   var iconTickerLeagueDefault = true;

//Use current league logos
   var logoTickerLeagueDefault = false;

//Delay in seconds between displayed matchups
   var tickerDelay = 3;

//Set the number of decimal places
   var tickerDecimals = 0;

//Display Live Scoring Caption above ticker
   var useLiveScoringCaption = true;

//Hide ties when displaying (W-L-T)
   var hideTiesInRecord = true;

//Hide point spreads for upcoming games
   var hideTickerSpread = true;

//Display ticker on home page only (useful if ticker is in the header)
   var tickerHomeOnly = true;

//Franchise Name or Nickname display
  var hideTickerName = true;
  var useTickerNickNames = false;

//Set up your Nick names here if you choose to use them
   var franchiseNickNames = new Object();  
   franchiseNickNames['0001'] = 'NICK 1';  
   franchiseNickNames['0002'] = 'NICK 2';  
   franchiseNickNames['0003'] = 'NICK 3';  
   franchiseNickNames['0004'] = 'NICK 4 ';
//         .
//         .
//        etc.


//-->
</script>



<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dagrafixdesigns.com/Templates/DA-2011/js/habman_common.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dagrafixdesigns.com/Templates/DA-2011/js/ticker.js"></script>    
</div>
```

I am left to remove this code to fix it then I will do so, but I wanted to see if it can be fixed first. Something with the new servers don't like these scripts obviously.
Thank you.

Comment: I've edited your question title, but JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: @JaredSmith We must of done it at the same time then, oops.

Comment: There is nothing here that would make this related to the servers it is on - there are no requests going to the server and everything happens in the browser.

Comment: I see no fewer than 6 errors in the console on that site, none of which are related to the code you posted. I also see that you are sending your user's passwords in plaintext, and that you have some shady ads running (last is not necessarily your fault).

Comment: I don't control any ads or passwords, that is the host company MFL... I just add code as a skin over top there software only...

Comment: If I remove that above code the site loads fast in chrome and FF....so I just assumed it was one of the 2 or both JS files from the ticker causing it to hang then load.....never acted this way prior to their move to new servers

Comment: @DA-G-GURU in that case, be aware that your hosting company is sending your user's (friend's? coworker's? customer's?) passwords in plain text, and hosting some shady ads.

Comment: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had a look at your js in chrome dev tools and in habman_common.js you do a document.write which adds a script tag which tries to get this js from this url (which no longer exists):

http://football.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2018/mfl_player_database.js

This seems to have now changed to:

http://home.myfantasyleague.com/fflnet2018/mfl_player_database.js

If you update your js to use this URL instead it should be ok.

You can see this by opening up chrome dev tools, clicking the network tab and ordering by time.

Comment: You get +1 for teaching a man to fish.

Comment: Since I know very little about JS and I mean VERY LITTLE...@magrangs you are special, thank you for all you do and helping me out. I was able to change the file where you specified and all is ok now. Your an asset to the world! TY again.

Comment: @jarredsmith if you can please release the hold, since the question was finalized quickly and it finished, next time I can repost a new question under that format ok. I would thank you.

Comment: @magrangs  Sir when in chrome inspect tools, mentioned above.....how did you know the answer was removing football and replacing with home? How would I be able to know this in the future per se?

Comment: @DA-G-GURU I went to the myfantasyleague website and noticed that the url was prefixed with home. I just tried it on the off chance that it would work!